# How to set into variable 1st value from subquery result in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm not so good with SQL, so help me please. 
In my stored procedure I'm getting a parameter.
Then, based on this parameter I want to get ID from another table and put this ID into my another variable, but the problem is that ID could be multiple based on this parameter.

```
DECLARE @RateID int;

SET @RateID = (
    Select [dbo].[Rate].RateID
    from [dbo].[Rate]
    Where [dbo].[Rate].Rate = 160       
)
```

Here I'm getting the error, because `Subquery returned more than 1 value`
How to get the first value from subquery result and set to the @RateID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try it like this:

```
DECLARE @RateID int;

SET @RateID = (
    Select Top 1 [dbo].[Rate].RateID
    from [dbo].[Rate]
    Where [dbo].[Rate].Rate = 160       
)
```

As in your present query there may be the case that you table has more than 1 row which satisfies the condition `Rate = 160`, so the `select` query will return more than 1 row which you cannot store in a single variable.

However in **MYSQL** you have to use `LIMIT 1` as `TOP 1` will not work in MYSQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the first result you can do

```
Select TOP 1 [dbo].[Rate].RateID
```

in place of

```
Select [dbo].[Rate].RateID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Top query like `SET @RateID = (
    Select  Top 1 [dbo].[Rate].RateID
    from [dbo].[Rate]
    Where [dbo].[Rate].Rate = 160

)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax:

```
Select top 1
  @RateId = RateId
from
  Rate
where
  Rate.Rate = @Rate
order by
  RateId
```

If you want the last, you can change the order by to:

```
order by
    RateId Desc
```

[Sql Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/196e2/3)